# Check if a movie/zip/audio file is legal

Tags: unix, owncloud

I am running a server with owncloud for a bunch of users.
However, i totally forbid the usage of this cloud for illegal stuff, like movies/audio/album/zip containing tv shows etc.

How can i be sure that users won't store files downloaded from torrent websites ?

Is there a unix binary that can fetch some screenshots from the mkv/avi file, and check whether there is a watermark or a known picture (20th century fox, warner etc.)

I cannot search for weird strange names like 'DVDRIP', since filenames are encrypted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with computing but legal stuff.

Comment: IMO, the only entity capable of finding whether a file is legal or not for a given owner is *court*.

Comment: @alamar The owner get's to decide how the item may be used. If the owner has not provided explicit permission do not host it. The copyright law in the US is such that no copyright notice is necessary so it is best to assume everything is copyrighted.

Comment: @zaph then you can't host any file then since everything is made by somebody.

Comment: You can host any file that the user created, any file that states it is public domain, any file the user has explicit permission (generally in writing) to upload. The content owner gets to decide how the content that he created is used, seems fair to me and probably sounds fair for any content you create. There are fair use exceptions and exceptions for the purchaser for their own only use.